# Change file create pattern in angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to change Angular CLI config to add `.interface` to interface files. Now when I create interface it has the same name as class for this interface, so it's tricky for another people in my team, for example now I have:

```
icar.ts
export interface ICar {
   ...
}
```

and:

```
car.ts
export class Car implements ICar{
   ...
}
```

But I want something like with service:

```
car.interface.ts
export interface CarInterface {
   ...
}
```

and

```
car.ts
export class Car implements CarInterface {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do with angular-cli.json.
Here is the schema of the config file : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/08bb738af2a3a257e003081caa154f014cb5365b/packages/angular-cli/lib/config/schema.json

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want could be technically achieved with the new Schematics feature in the Angular CLI. But it may take quite some time to figure it out. There are some links at the [Schematics documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7627) thread.